# Selenium Webdriver opening multiple windows - Regular browser doesnt

Tags: selenium, drupal, selenium-webdriver, junit, automated-tests

I've searched and searched, and I cannot seem to find an answer to this specific problem.

Here's the situation: Using any Webdriver (IE, FireFox, or Chrome), on a single specific page, using a .click command on any of the links on the page causes a new window to open. This then causes the original window to die, and my tests can't find the next elements in the script.

This behavior is not replicated if I open a browser manually and do the exact same steps.

Using a normal manual browser, When I do a right click on the element and inspect it, I see this line:

```
<a>class="" href="/new-page-link" title="">Link Title</a>
```

However, when I open a webdriver, and inspect the exact same element from the same page, I see:

```
<a>target="_blank" href="/new-page-link" title="" class="active-trail active">Link Title</a>
```

Here's the kicker; I ONLY see this behavior if I log into the site using my developer credentials in the URL, such as http://user:pass@website.com/

Any ideas?

On request, here is a the (very basic) webdriver code:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
BrowserType = "Firefox";

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("www.MyUrl.com");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Link Text")).click();
```

Comment: It's hacky, but have you tried explicitly stating target="_self"? As to why, I have no idea. Out of curriosity is the closing carrot > after the "<a" intentional?

Comment: Can you please share webdriver code?

Comment: Webdriver code provided. The actual code for the test is much more complex, but even a VERY basic test like the above will fail as well.

Comment: As for explicitly stating target="_self", if you mean on the webpage, I can't do that because I dont control that codebase.

If you mean in the Webdriver, forcing target = self, I assume thats the same as what Dharam recommended? I'll take a look today on trying that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming if that's the way WebDriver is altering the behaviour, why not try this hack -

```
WebElement objLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/new-page-link']"));
WebElement objNewLink = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('target','_self')",objLink );
objNewLink.click();
```